# Cantor's snake-like path function

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to develop an algorithm that demonstrates that the set of rational is countable. 
The idea of the proof is to arrange rational numbers into the diagram shown below:

[Cantor's snake diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHDwk.png)

Index:     0      1       2    3    4    5    6    ...

Rational:  1/1   2/1  1/2  1/3  2/2  3/1  4/1  ...

Thus any given rational number has its unambiguous index along the path, and conversely, any index uniquely identifies a rational number.

I tried to implement that diagram using the cantor's pairing function , but it doses not return the correct values.

[Cantor Pairing formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBeFJ.png)

Expected result:

15 / 17

15 / 17 -> 479

1   /1

1 / 1 -> 0

666/666

666 / 666 -> 885780

Cantor's paring Function result :

15 / 17

15 / 17 -> 543

1  / 1

1 / 1 -> 4

666 / 666

666 / 666 -> 888444

Comment: Note that 1/1 = 2/2 = 3/3 = 1 ... be careful when you say "any given rational number has its unambiguous index".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us fix notation and say that 
$$ \mathbb{N} = \text{Non-negative integers} $$
and
$$ \mathbb{N}_+ = \text{Positive integers} $$

The Cantor pairing function establishes a bijection between $\mathbb{N}^2$ and $\mathbb{N}$. You are after the function giving the bijection between $\mathbb{N}_+^2$ and $\mathbb{N}$. So clearly the Cantor pairing function is not what you are looking for.

Fortunately, what you are looking for is simply an offset of Cantor's pairing function
$$ (k_1, k_2) \mapsto \pi(k_1 - 1, k_2 - 1)$$

You get

$$ (1,1) \mapsto 0 $$
$$  (14,16) \mapsto 481 $$
$$ (666,666) \mapsto 885780 $$

The second line doesn't agree because you also misinterpreted the way Cantor's function snakes through the pairings. See [this picture on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#/media/File:Pairing_natural.svg) instead.

Comment: This is great! it works flawlessly. thank you !
How can we also implement the reverse for this formula? for example instead of giving it (14,16) ↦ 481 we specify 481 and it returns (14,16)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Inverting_the_Cantor_pairing_function

Comment: You said  Cantor pairing function is not what you i am looking for. But what i needed was an offset of Cantor's pairing function , but what you shared with me was the reversal of cantor's pairing function and not the reverse of the offset of cantor's pairing function

Comment: @Yunislav: I'm afraid I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I meant the Wikipedia page has the reversal formula for cantor pairing formula and not the offset of it.
I want the reversal formula for the offset of cantor pairing formula

Comment: Suppose $z \mapsto (x,y)$ is the formula given on Wikipedia for the reverse of the Cantor pairing function. Then since your function is $(k_1, k_2) \mapsto \pi(k_1 - 1, k_2 - 1)$, you can just put in the off-set yourself: the function that sends $z \mapsto (x+1,y+1)$ would be the reverse of the offset.