# What is the cardinality of N × N? Modulo arithmetic

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The following two questions stump me. Will you please help me?

**What is the cardinality of N × N?**
Countably infinite. But how do I prove it? By listing ordered pairs?

**What is the truth value of this?**
∀a, b ∈ Z: (a ≡ b (mod 5) ⇒ 2a ≡ 2b (mod 5))

I'm assuming that since the solution set stays the same when you multiply by a constant, then the remainder remains the same, is key part to solving it. How do I fare?

Comment: These are two unrelated questions, which should be posted separately.  The first has been covered many times here.

Answer (score 1):

Those really should be two separate questions. For the first, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1993342/cantors-snake-like-path-function). For the second, note $a-b=5k\implies 2a-2b=5(2k)$.